# How to remove property of ui component in pyside/pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have set property to QLineEdit as

```
self.ui.txtName.setProperty('rules', 'required')
```

I want to remove this property dynamically, is there any way to do so,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html#dynamic-properties) say:

> ...
>
> A property can be removed from an instance by passing the property
> name and an invalid QVariant value to QObject::setProperty(). The
> default constructor for QVariant constructs an invalid QVariant.

and this works for PyQt:

```
self.ui.txtName.setProperty("rules", QtCore.QVariant())
#or 
self.ui.txtName.setProperty("rules", None)
```

Comment: The `QVariant` isn't really needed: `None` will do the same thing.